# Does anyone know how to add legend for a WMS layer in leaflet R?

Tags: r, leaflet, wms

Does anyone know how to  add a legend for WMS Tile layer in leaflet R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use `addWMSLegend()` in leaflet.extras. You could set the correct uri of WMS legend service to `addWMSLegend()`.Here is an example:

```
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras)
leaflet()%>%
    addTiles(urlTemplate = 'the url of your basemap service',
        options=tileOptions(useCache=T,crossOrigin=T))%>%
    addWMSTiles(baseUrl = 
        paste0('http://',geoserver.host,':8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wms'),
        layers ='workspace:layer',
        options = WMSTileOptions(format = "image/png", transparent = TRUE),
        attribution = "")%>%
    addWMSLegend(uri=paste0('http://',geoserver.host,
        ':8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wms?',
        'REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&VERSION=1.0.0',
        '&FORMAT=image/png&LAYER=workspace:layer'))
```